# facebook API ERROR : Unauthorized source IP address

Tags: php, facebook, curl

getting this error after execting this php code in webhost (cloudaccess.net).

> {"error":{"message":"(#5) Unauthorized source IP address","type":"OAuthException","code":5}}

can anyone can help me...?

```
<?php error_reporting(0);
    function url_get_contents ($url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
$graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=VALID_TOKEN';
$graph_data = url_get_contents($graph_url);

echo $graph_data;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address from which you're trying to use the Facebook API from is blacklisted, because someone else using the same IP address has violated the Facebook API Terms of Service. Unfortunately there's little you can do about that. The only way to get it working again is to get another IP address. I don't know a thing about cloudaccess.net, so I can't give an indication of how hard that will be or if it is even possible. Another possibility would be to proxy your requests through another IP address, but that would probably require another hosting account somewhere else and a whole new level of infrastructure.